# Как реализовать калькулятор на woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Как реализовать покупку через калькулятор? В калькуляторе может быть миллион вариаций товара, так как цена меняется от размера окна и т.д. То есть вариативными товарами реализовать не получится. Как сделать так что б человек мог заказать и оплатить, окно которое он собрал?

Может есть какой-то плагин для таких целей? Просто такая задача встречается уже не в первый раз и я не понимаю как можно это реализовать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://hoicker.com/woocommerce-composite-product-plugins/

Comment: @Алексей по моему это немного не то. В плагинах выбираются готовые варианты. А у меня целый конструктор у которого миллион вариаций.